# How to find the distance between the elements of a list?

Tags: python, list, zip

I have list `L1 = [123,543]` , `L2 = [321,279]`.  using Zip we can combine two lists

```
n = [list(a) for a in zip(L1,L2)]
for i in (n):
    print (i)
```

Output:

```
[123, 321]
[543, 279]
```

How to find the distance between the elements of List in python?
Example: The difference between `123` and `321` is `0` (2 + 0  -2).
The difference between `543` and `279` is `6` (-3 + 3 + 6).

Comment: Please show your efforts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `zip` again to find the difference of digits and take sum:

```
L1 = [123,543]
L2 = [321,279]

lst = []
for x, y in zip(L1, L2):
   lst.append(sum(int(b) - int(a) for a, b in zip(str(x), str(y))))

print(lst)
# [0, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This One:

```
In [37]: for i,j in zip(L1, L2):
    ...:     b = list(map(int,list(str(i))))
    ...:     c = list(map(int,list(str(j))))
    ...:     d = [x1 - x2 for (x1, x2) in zip(b, c)]
    ...:     print(sum(d))
```